# Postgresql 10 - Configurações do Parallel

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Existem 4 configurações para ativar o `parallel` e fazer as otimizaçoes, mas a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/parallel-query.html) do PostgreSQL não diz nada sobre valores ou cálculos. Minhas perguntas são:

> 1- Como calcular os valores de `max_parallel_workers`,
>   `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` e `max_worker_processes`?
>
> 2- O `work_mem` pode ser calculado na base de conexões e memória (RAM),
>   mas o `work_mem` precisa mudar alguma coisa se eu habilitar o paralelo?

Minha suposição é: se a máquina tiver 8 núcleos, o `max_parallel_workers` seria 8 e os valores do processo worker e por gather seriao 32 (8 * 4), o número 4 que tirei da configuração original que é 4 gathers por 1 parallel work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após algumas pesquisas encontrei algumas respostas, isso pode ajudar quem quer habilitar e ter uma configuração base, caso tenha 4 núcleos (CPU):

seus max worker processes 'e a quantidade de núcleos e o máximo de parallel precisa ter a mesma quantidade:

```
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers = 4
```

o gather é mais complexa porque esse valor pode ser manipulado com base em suas necessidades e recursos, é necessário testar para obter um melhor resultado, mas para valores de inicialização você pode usar (núcleos/2).

```
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
```

Esta não é uma resposta final, há alguns pontos em falta ... Ainda estou pesquisando e atualizando esta resposta ou esperando por uma melhor.